# dedup in elasticsearch for duplicate documents

Tags: search, elasticsearch, duplicates

Find duplicate documents and remove them using dedup option.
how to achieve this during index creation time? 
we have tired this option but doing during query time below is the sample example

```
    GET /employeeid/info/_search? "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "field": "name",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

can we achieve the same in indexing time ?

Comment: If you need your documents to be unique by name then is there any reasons not to use name as the Id? 

If you did it this way elasticsearch will take care of overwriting (delete-replacing) the previous document of the same id, as an added advantage elasticsearch will version your documents and you will be able to use GET's to pull individual employee's by name

Comment: @ Mic987 58 The problem here is if suppose i have the name as 'General Motors California' twice then when i search for certain documents I should bring one document to the bottom of the search ? How to achieve this ?

Comment: I think you might need to include more information in your post. Post the query you would be using and what results you would expect to see. Sorry I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For eg :if i have a word in a document called "google india,google singapore,google malayisa ,microsoft" we also have a copy to filed which copies all these same names now when i do search the name "google" results should come in top ,because of more google terms the term frequency is very low ,In the copy to filed these term should treated only once how to achieve this ?